# MVC Working with Multiple Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller

I'm still learning MVC and have gone through several online tutorials. But I'm missing something sort of vital to my application, so this is a general question not necessarily requiring code examples to answer. If you can just steer me in the right direction in conceptual terms...

My application is completely read-only to the database, I don't need or want to write back. I need to pull data from multiple tables in one database, which are the exact same schema, into what I think would be a single model that I can then filter, then display the results. To complicate things somewhat, the table names need to be variables, these tables are built upstream on the fly using the date as part of the table name.

The tables are television automation schedules, different table for each day, but each contain a number of fields for scheduled time, house ID, title, etc. I need to get several days into one model (I think), and then I'm going to query a different database that will tell me for each row in the table whether the House ID exists on a video server or not. I want to then display the list of rows that do not exist in the video server.

I have an example in VB but feel like I should tackle this in C# as it seems to be more universally supported.

I don't think I can use VS tools to create a model from the database table since the table name is different every day.

So is the proper plan of attack to load the multiple table data into one model?
Maybe I don't even need a model in the true sense of the word, there's no binding required to be able to write the data back to the db. I just essentially need to load the table data into an array, doesn't need to continue to be bound to the db, that I can then analyze and figure out which of these items don't exist in the server.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099435/dynamic-table-name-in-linq) SO question and [this](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic) NuGet package. Maybe this will fit your needs.

Comment: Models in MVC were originally meant to be state machines that could encapsulate any amount of data from any sources as needed to inform a view. It's unfortunate that in many so-called MVC frameworks, they've become equated to rows due to the use of object-relational mappers. I would just build a SQL query to union the results required and retrieve it as a dataset.