# Run LINQ query with dynamic table name

Tags: c#, linq

I try to run LINQ query. As you can see from the code below, I try to name the table ("TableName") before passing it to LINQ, and of course LINQ can't find a table named "TableName". Any other way around how to do this? I tried ctxdata.(TableName) but didn't work.

```
            var TableName = "";
            TableName = "DATA_ + DistrictCode;

            using (SFTEMPEntities1 ctxdata = new SSFTEMPEntities1())
            {
                var queryAttributes = (from p in ctxdata.TableName //See this line 
                                   where p.Filename == FileName
                                   select new { p.REF , p.JOB_TITLE })
                                   .Take(1);


            }
```

I'm still a newbie on C# , really appreciate if you can show me example based on this code.

Comment: Maybe this question (and the linked questions) can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099435/dynamic-table-name-in-linq

Answer (score 1):

You can get table from data context using `Set` method but you need type of it's elements like generic parameter `Set<T>()` or just `Type` variable `Set(Type type)`. So you need to find some way to get type by table name. If you have type name you can get type by name from assembly  `ctxdata.GetType().Assembly.GetType("TypeName")`.

Using reflection you can get table property from data context like this:

```
var table = ctxdata.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(ctxdata) as IQueryable;
```