# check if context has some table then add to this table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, reflection

i have multiple DbContexts and each context has some DbSets like

```
public class fooContext : DbContext 
{
    DbSet<fooA> fooA {get,set}
    DbSet<fooB> fooB {get,set}
}

public class barContext : DbContext 
{
    DbSet<barA> barA {get,set}
    DbSet<barB> barB {get,set}
}
```

and an excel file with  multiple excelSheets 
structered properly for linqtosql to work with
(having sheet names as fooA,fooB... ,first row is properties names and remaining rows are data)

i can see that if i have which context has fooA i can [use something like this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099435/dynamic-table-name-in-linq) inside the context

```
public DbSet Set(string "fooA")
{
  return base.Set(Type.GetType("fooA"));
}
```

but i don't which context has fooA to add this to

to clarify this ,, normally when you want to add `fooARecord` to `fooA` table in `fooContext` you

```
fooContext.fooA.Add(fooARecord);
```

but i only have fooA as string and fooARecord

**P.S**: cant use linqtosql since oracle and i cant simply import excel to oracle coz too many tables and users need to be able to alter this data before this process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check is a fooContext has a DbSet of a specific type only by name, you can do this:

```
var fooContext = new FooContext(); //the context to check

var dbSets = fooContext.GetType().GetProperties()
                                    .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                                    && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                                    == typeof(DbSet<>)).ToArray(); //List Dbset<T>

var fooA = "fooA"; //the table to search

var dbSetProp = dbSets.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name == fooA);
if(dbSetProp != null) {
    //fooContext has fooA table
    var dbSet = fooContex.Set(dbSetProp.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]); // or via dbSetProp.GetValue(fooContext) as DbSet
    dbSet.Add(fooARecord);
}
```